# Search multiple fields rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following form:

```
<div class='panel' id='panel-advanced-search'>
  <%= form_tag contacts_path, method: :get do %>
    <div>
      <div class='advanced_search'>
        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Contact Type" %>
          <%= select_tag(:contact_type, options_for_select(Contact::TYPES, selected: params[:contact_type]), prompt: 'Any', class: 'customSelect') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Prospect Strength" %>
          <%= select_tag(:prospect_strength, options_for_select(Contact::PROSPECT_STRENGTHS, selected: params[:prospect_strength]), prompt: 'Any', class: 'customSelect') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Customer" %>
          <%= collection_select(:customer_account_id, :customer_account_id, Customer.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: '' }, class: 'customSelect select2') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Supplier" %>
          <%= collection_select(:supplier_account_id, :supplier_account_id, Supplier.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: '' }, class: 'customSelect select2') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Company Name" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :company_name %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Name" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :name %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Job Title" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :title %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Postcode" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :postcode %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag :created_at, 'Created From' %>

          <div class="date-picker">
            <%= text_field_tag :created_at, nil, class: 'date-picker-select' %>

            <span class="date-picker-btn">
              <span class="icon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag :updated_at, 'Created To' %>

          <div class="date-picker">
            <%= text_field_tag :updated_at, nil, class: 'date-picker-select' %>

            <span class="date-picker-btn">
              <span class="icon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Tags" %>
          <%= collection_select(:tag_list, :tag_list, @tags.order(:name), :name, :name, {}, { class: 'select2', multiple: true }) %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Assignee" %>
          <%= collection_select(:assigned_to, :assigned_to, User.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Any' }, class: 'customSelect select2') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Obsolete?" %>
          <%= select_tag(:obsolete, options_for_select(['Obsolete', 'All'], selected: params[:obsolete]), prompt: 'Not obsolete?', class: 'customSelect') %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= label_tag "Send Results To" %>
          <%= select_tag(:subsequent_action, options_for_select([
            ['Report', 'report'],
            ['CSV Export', 'csv_export'],
            ['New Event', 'new_event']
          ]), prompt: 'None', class: 'customSelect') %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="advanced_search_btns">
        <%= submit_tag submit_text %>
        <%= link_to secondary_btn, contacts_path, class: 'btn-medium' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the following method in the model

```
def self.advanced_search
  Contact.where('
    contact_type LIKE :search OR
    prospect_strength LIKE :search OR
    customer_account_id LIKE :search OR
    supplier_account_id LIKE :search OR
    company_name LIKE :search OR
    name LIKE :search OR
    title LIKE :search OR
    postcode LIKE :search OR
    created_at LIKE :search OR
    updated_at LIKE :search OR
    tag_list LIKE :search OR
    assigned_to LIKE :search OR
    obsolete LIKE :search
  ', search: "%#{search}%"
  )
end
```

How do I go about using this method so the user can use this search form with multiple params? I already have the following in the index method for a basic search so I need to have both search forms

```
def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || 20
  @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all

  if params[:search].present?
    @contacts = Contact.search(params[:qs], params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: @per_page)
  else
    @contacts = Contact.all.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: @per_page)
  end
end
```

**Edit** Updated the form above to the complete form, ideally, I would like the forms functionality to be entirely in the model.

**Edit #2**

This is the basic search:

**model**

```
QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS = {
  name: {
    column_names: 'contacts.name'
  },
  customers: {
    joins_table: :customer,
    column_names: 'contacts.name',
    filters: { contact_type: 'customer' }
  },
  suppliers: {
    joins_table: :supplier,
    column_names: 'contacts.name',
    filters: { contact_type: 'supplier' }
  },
  tags: {
    tagged_with: true
  }
}.with_indifferent_access

def self.search(field, query)
  field = QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS[field]

  contact = all
  contact = contact.joins(field[:joins_table]) if field[:joins_table]
  contact = contact.where(field[:filters]) if field[:filters]
  contact = contact.where("#{field[:column_names]} LIKE ?", "%#{query}%") if field[:column_names]
  contact = contact.tagged_with(query) if field[:tagged_with]
  contact
end
```

**form**

```
<div class='panel' id='panel-search'>
  <%= form_tag contacts_path, method: :get do %>
    <div class='l-inline-row-block'>
      <div class='l-inline-col width_120px'>
        <%= select_tag(:qs, options_for_select(Contact::QUICK_SEARCH_FIELDS.keys(), selected: params[:qs]), class: 'customSelect') %>
      </div>

      <div class='l-inline-col'>
        <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      </div>

      <div class='l-inline-col' style='width: 100px;'>
        <%= submit_tag submit_text %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: in advanced search: the user can select a value out of the multiple fields to search in, but can he also keep the field empty e.g: the user wants to search for content in `contact_type ` but not in `prospect_strength`? also can the search term be different between fields?

Comment: That's correct yes, also yes the search term can be different between fields, but also if the user wants to search `contact_type` and `prospect_strength` they should be able to as well as any other fields they want to add to the search.

Comment: I see you need to have the simple form and the advanced search: but not at the same time right? or do they? which one takes precedent? if the advanced search is there do also search with the normal one?

Comment: Not at the same time no, it's up to the user which one they want to use there both completely separate. Tabs wise the basic search tab is first so that's what the user sees first but there's no field sharing or anything between the two. Both searches are on the page at the same time but completely separate forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to make view adjustments and you cannot just use the `search` term/query for all fields:

1.make sure the fields inside the form in your view are all the same names of the columns in the Contact model that need to be searched
2.add a hidden field inside each form so you can determine which search this is (there is another option but this one is less work)
3.change the collection_select where user can only select one field to select_tag in order to not mess up query building

every field that is filled will pass a value- you can build a hash including column/form-field entered and their value e.g `{ contact_type: "value1", prospect_strength: "value2" }`

after that, you would need to build a query using that hash and query the DB

this would look like so:

### In your view:

add this in the advanced search form

`<%= hidden_field_tag :search_type, :advanced %>`

and in your normal search add this

`<%= hidden_field_tag :search_type, :normal %>`

### In your model:

```rb
def self.advanced_search(values_by_column_name) # values_by_column_name is a hash passed from the controller
    tag_list = values_by_column_name.delete("tag_list")
    sql_query = values_by_column_name.keys.map { |column| "#{column} LIKE :#{column}" }
    sql_query = sql_query.join(" OR ")
    values_by_column_name = values_by_column_name.transform_values { |value| "%#{value}%" }.symbolize_keys

    relation = Contact.where(sql_query, values_by_column_name)
    relation = relation.tagged_with(tag_list) if tag_list
    relation
end
```

### in your controller:

```rb
ADVANCED_SEARCH_FIELDS = [
    :contact_type,
    :prospect_strength,
    :customer_account_id,
    :supplier_account_id,
    :company_name,
    :name,
    :title,
    :postcode,
    :created_at,
    :updated_at,
    {tag_list: []},
    :assigned_to,
    :obsolete,
]

def index
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || 20
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all

    if advanced_search?
        @contacts = Contact.advanced_search(advanced_search_params)
    elsif normal_search?
        @contacts = Contact.search(params[:qs], params[:search])
    else
        @contacts = Contact.all
    end

    @contacts = @contacts.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: @per_page)
end

def advanced_search?
    params[:search_type] == "advanced" && advanced_search_params.any?
end

def normal_search?
    params[:search_type] == "normal" && params[:search].present?
end

def advanced_search_params
    @_advanced_search_params ||= params.permit(ADVANCED_SEARCH_FIELDS).select { |_, v| v.present? }.to_h
end
```

Comment: Would it be possible to move the advanced search fields into the model, as this is a db query that should belong in the model ideally? Also there are different field types not just select fields, so there's text and select fields

Comment: what do you mean? where are the advanced search fields now? aren't all those fields in the contact db?

Comment: Let me update the question with the whole form, all of these fields are in the contact table yes. There shouldn't be any defaults for the advanced search it should be blank so we shouldn't default to the `contact_type`

Comment: I understood could you possibly comment here: the params in case of an advanced search and the params in case of normal search? i want to see the difference and if there is any special keys that would help up determine the difference

Comment: Do you mean to add the basic search form to the question? I'm not sure what you mean by special keys, both forms are blank on load and should remain blank if it's not used. If this helps this is what I mean by tabs and it being two separate forms https://i.gyazo.com/48ad9e782a006e9c96612e17f8371a41.mp4

Comment: I'll update the question with the basic search one second @Mshka

Comment: Updated with the basic search

Comment: i mean the params when they hit the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231332/discussion-between-mshka-and-debugabug).